# Titanium appcelerator createHTTPClient() not working Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I´m making a simple GET request in titanium and it seems to be that in versions of android 5.0 and up doesn´t work correctly. Here is the response of the console that im receiving.

> < ANDROID 5.0
>
> [INFO] :   Status: 200, connectionType: GET
>
> => ANDROID 5.0
>
> {"source":{"password":null,"status":0,"username":null,"autoRedirect":true,"bubbleParent":true,"allResponseHeaders":"","location":"","autoEncodeUrl":true,"apiName":"Ti.Network.HTTPClient","responseXML":null,"validatesSecureCertificate":false,"readyState":1,"domain":null,"responseText":"","responseData":null,"connectionType":"GET","statusText":null,"connected":false,"_events":{"disposehandle":{}}},"error":"Handshake
>   failed","code":-1,"success":false}
>
> ERROR: "**Handshake failed**"

Here is the code that im using.

```
var url = "MY URL";

        var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

        loader.onload = function() 
        {
            Titanium.API.info('Status: ' + this.status);
            Titanium.API.info('ResponseText: ' + this.responseText);
            Titanium.API.info('connectionType: ' + this.connectionType);
            Titanium.API.info('location: ' + this.location);
        };

        loader.onerror = function (e) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
          console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(e.error));
        };

        loader.open("GET",url);
        loader.send();
```

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: It seems to be that if you are using a **https://**  url the request will not work in Android 5.0 and up.

What I did is remove the **S** and just leave it as http, but this is not a permanent solution because there might be web services that requires https://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the SSL certificate of the webserver.

You can verify that the certificate is valid from Chrome:

[image: SLL Facebook]